# Java compare two sub objects

Tags: java, object, equals

I have a class - it has a field "id", which is an int. Let's call this class "Author".

I have another class, it has a field "author", which is an "Author". Let's call this class "Book".

If I have two book objects, what is the best way to note the difference (if any) in the id of the author?

The "id" field could be null, and the "author" field could also be null. Is there some pre-written code that can handle all the plausible permutations for null checks?

Comment: [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You must correctly implement ***equals*** method for your classes, looking also at inner objects, using something like this

```
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o == this) return true;
  if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;
  Book other = (Book) o;
  if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
  if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
  if (!this.other.author.equals(this.author)) return false;
  return true;
}
```

If don't want particular behaviour you can use Lombok with its [@EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) annotation

Comment: _very important_: Do not ever override equals without also overriding hashCode and vice versa. These 2 methods must go hand in hand. Overriding only equals and not hashCode means that, for example, putting Books into HashSets or use them as keys in HashMaps give bizarre and completely broken behaviour.

Comment: `if (!super.equals(o)) return false;` is redundant, surely. You've already checked `o == this`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yeh, i'm avoiding the equals override for the reason that i only care about the id in my particular use case, and of course the object itself has other fields that are redundant for the question at hand.

Comment: i was really hoping java had some hidden null-optional handler that i just wasn't aware of, but it doesn't. But i'm curious - what does your "canEqual" drill into>

Comment: @bharal ok you can focus on a specific override if you want to ignore other fields